# How to concat python lxml trees

Tags: python, lxml

I'm working with the freshbooks api using the refreshbooks[1] python script they've created. I'm limited to 100 results per call, so I was trying to put a group of calls together to put together a large list of elements to use with jquery datatables. My question is how do I concat two of these element trees?

Here are two simple calls that grab one result at a time:

```
client_response = c.client.list(
    per_page=1,
    page=1
)
client_response2 = c.client.list(
    per_page=1,
    page=2
)
```

And the basic response in client_response.clients looks like:

```
<clients xmlns="http://www.freshbooks.com/api/" page="1" per_page="1" pages="2" total="2">
    <client>...</client>
</clients>
```

I've tried treating them as lists and using .extend but have had no luck.

Updated: the objects are actually lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement objects, not truly trees, but my question still stands on how to concat these...

[1] http://pypi.python.org/pypi/refreshbooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to concatenate these items into list by first converting the items to lists then extending:

```
clients = list(client_response.clients.client)
clients.extend(list(client_response2.clients.client))
```